# xsetroot, xterm and twm are not found when starting XRDP/Xvnc (on Cent OS)

Tags: centos, vnc

I am trying to install `xrdp` service on one my VPS server, and though all installed successfully I get following error after connecting via Windows MSTSC service.

Following are the resources I have used to install => ***[(1)](http://linuxtoolkit.blogspot.in/2013/04/starting-vnc-server-no-displays.html) [(2)](http://ajmatson.net/wordpress/2014/01/install-xrdp-remote-desktop-to-centos-6-5/) [(3)](http://thornelabs.net/2013/06/28/rhel-6-fix-xrdp-error-another-xserver-is-already-active-on-display-10.html) [(4)](http://uwot.eu/blog/2013/04/xrdp-and-centos-6/) [(5)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1314336) [(6)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xrdp/+bug/375755)***

Imagine this as GUI Window -> [Sample](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-1HyaZXvmdKo/UWTJCOs0WyI/AAAAAAAAA3A/mjRXiK38VF0/s1600/xrdp_error1.JPG)

```
Connection Log
    connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
    sesman connect ok
    sending login info to session manager, please wait ...
    xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login successful for display
    started connecting
    connecting to 127.0.0.1 5911
    error - problem connecting
```

and following is the error log I see from `/var/log/xrdp-sesman.log`

```
[20140328-19:50:31] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 7 started successfully
[20140328-19:50:32] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username root, ip my.ip.addr.ess:63327 - socket: 7
[20140328-19:50:32] [INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
[20140328-19:50:32] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sessvc - xpid=7552 - wmpid=7551
[20140328-19:50:32] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username root, display :11.0, session_pid 7549, ip my.ip.addr.ess:63327 - socket: 7
```

and following are the logs of my `/root/.vnc/servername:2.log`

```
Xvnc TigerVNC 1.1.0 - built Feb  4 2014 05:26:31
Copyright (C) 1999-2011 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 11300000, The X.Org Foundation

Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension VNC
Initializing built-in extension GLX

Fri Mar 28 19:36:33 2014
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5902
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
/root/.vnc/xstartup: line 27: xsetroot: command not found
/root/.vnc/xstartup: line 28: xterm: command not found
/root/.vnc/xstartup: line 29: twm: command not found
```

And Following are the commands I used to install `tigervnc-server` and `xrdp` on my two cent OS.

```
root@servername [~]#  cat /etc/*-release
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
root@servername [~]# yum install xrdp tigervnc-server
root@servername [~]# service vncserver start
Starting VNC server: no displays configured                [FAILED]
root@servername [~]#
root@servername [~]#  vim /etc/sysconfig/vncservers
VNCSERVERS="2:root"
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 800x600 -nolisten tcp -localhost"
:wq!
root@servername [~]# service vncserver start
Starting VNC server: 2:root
New 'servername:2 (root)' desktop is servername:2

Starting applications specified in /root/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /root/.vnc/servername:2.log

                                                           [  OK  ]
root@servername [~]# service xrdp start
Starting xrdp:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting xrdp-sesman:                                      [  OK  ]
root@servername [~]# chkconfig xrdp on
root@servername [~]# chkconfig vncserver on
root@servername [~]# vncpasswd
Password:
Verify:
root@servername [~]#
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need to install X.  Your VNC server log says file not found for xsetroot, xterm, and twm.

See here:
http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-f9b66646092bdc0de1d8b4c82b427f796adfe2f8

Comment: that did resolve the problem. I ran following command `yum groupinstall "X Window System" "Desktop"` and then `init 6` to restart the server, and restarted `service vncserver restart` and `service xrdp restart`. How I can be grateful?

Comment: I found the following very helpful when troubleshooting, I could follow the errors in the config more easily.  note that the vncserver session isn't needed, xrdp will launch its own using its own session manager:  # xrdp --nodaemon& sleep 2; xrdp-sesman --nodaemon

Answer (score 0):

On a CentOS installation with either Desktop or Minimal Desktop. Go ahead and install epel repository. Then

```
yum install tiger* xrdp rdesktop
service xrdp restart
chkconfig xrdp on
```

Then you will be able to RDP from or into this PC/Server