# Issues in XRDP installation on Cent OS 6.5

Tags: linux, vnc, centos

I already went through the similar issue tracked in [xsetroot, xterm and twm are not found when starting XRDP/Xvnc (on Cent OS)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122031/installing-xrdp-on-cent-os-6-5), however it haven't helped me to fix.

I am using MAC and trying to install XRDP in CentOS release 6.5 (64 bit). So that I can connect to this Centos machine from MAC.

I followed the steps explained in http://ajmatson.net/wordpress/2014/01/install-xrdp-remote-desktop-to-centos-6-5/

Created a new VNC user account named ***user_name_one*** and allotted a password as mentioned in http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server

Now, when I tried to connect Centos using Remote Desktop Connection (from MAC), I am receiving following error:

[image]

Initially my vncservers configuration in etc/sysconfig/vncservers are as follows:

```
VNCSERVERS="1:user_name_one"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 800x600"
```

As suggested, now changed the config values as follows:

```
VNCSERVERS="0:user_name_one"
VNCSERVERARGS[0]="-geometry 800x600"
```

**Error log in /var/log/xrdp-sesman.log:**

```
[20140416-06:43:43] [WARN ] [init:45] libscp initialized
[20140416-06:43:43] [CORE ] starting sesman with pid 1442
[20140416-06:43:43] [INFO ] listening...
[20140416-06:46:56] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 7 started successfully
[20140416-06:46:56] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username user_name_one, ip 202.83.25.7:13889 - socket: 7
[20140416-06:46:56] [INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
[20140416-06:47:06] [ERROR] X server for display 10 startup timeout
[20140416-06:47:06] [INFO ] starting xrdp-sessvc - xpid=1717 - wmpid=1716
[20140416-06:47:06] [ERROR] X server for display 10 startup timeout
[20140416-06:47:07] [ERROR] another Xserver is already active on display 10
[20140416-06:47:07] [DEBUG] aborting connection...
[20140416-06:47:07] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username user_name_one, display :10.0, session_pid 1715, ip 202.83.25.7:13889 - socket: 7
```

**Log file found under /home/user_name_one/.vnc/SPU4-1-3-24-47230 :1.log**

```
Xvnc TigerVNC 1.1.0 - built Feb  4 2014 05:26:31
Copyright (C) 1999-2011 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 11300000, The X.Org Foundation

Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension VNC
Initializing built-in extension GLX

Wed Apr 16 06:43:46 2014
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5900
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
No protocol specified
vncconfig: unable to open display ":0"
No protocol specified
xrdb: Resource temporarily unavailable
xrdb: Can't open display ':0'
No protocol specified
xmodmap:  unable to open display ':0'
No protocol specified
No protocol specified

** (gnome-session:1605): WARNING **: Cannot open display:
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message is your issue:

```
Tue Apr 15 08:36:38 2014
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
No protocol specified
vncconfig: unable to open display ":1"
No protocol specified
xrdb: Can't open display ':1'
No protocol specified
xmodmap:  unable to open display ':1'
No protocol specified
No protocol specified

** (gnome-session:2967): WARNING **: Cannot open display:
```

You should be connecting to RDP on display `:0`. Double check that the display is set in your configuration files to `:0` instead of `:1`. Also make sure that the CentOS system is in runlevel 5 and not 3.

You can check like this:

```
$ runlevel 
N 5
```

If it's anything but 5, then run this command to temporarily switch it:

```
$ sudo telinit 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. My vncserver configuration in etc/sysconfig/vncservers are mapped to :1. Hence I received such error log. Thanks and now I have changed that to :0.. However, still I am getting similar error in log. I have updated the error logs and vncserver configuration in above question.. can you please help me in this..

Comment: Also, when I checked runlevel, its 'N 3'... as suggested I tried with telinit 5 command (to switch)... now the value is: '3 5'... Even now I am unable to connect using xrdp.. I also tried to change the default CentOS runlevel by editing the value in /etc/inittab file as 'id:5:initdefault:'. Rebooted server. now the value is 'N 5'. However, it haven't helped. I am getting the same error

Comment: @Kamal - just curious, I was able to get that same dialog message you did "error - problem connecting". When I tried it a second time I got my desktop. Can you confirm trying this 2-3 times and seeing if the issue repeats each time?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the same for more than 5 times. I am receiving the same error..

Comment: @Kamal - something to try. Can you comment out the VNCSERVER... lines in the file `/etc/sysconfig/vncserver` and restart xrdp and try again? Also make sure these pkgs are installed: `yum install pixman libXfont`.

Comment: I tried to install 'pixman' and 'libXfont' and found that these are already installed in my CentOS machine (pixman-0.26.2-5.1.el6_5.x86_64 and libXfont-1.4.5-3.el6_5.x86_64)... I also commented out the VNCSERVER in /etc/sysconfig/vncserver and when I restarted vncserver in terminal, I received a failure status while starting... xrdp restarted successfully. Still I am receiving the same error..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error as you did. Addressed it by installing some desktop packages. I suppose this would work:

```
yum groupinstall Desktop
```

I just installed `xterm` and a couple of other packages:

```
yum install xterm x-org-x11-fonts-Type1 xorg-x11-twm
```

Also, made a [barebone puppet module](https://github.com/belminf/puppet-xrdp/blob/master/manifests/init.pp) for it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add this solution:

```
sudo yum install tigervnc-server
```